# How to accommodate injectable middleware for global automatically in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

There is a way that allows registering interceptors in the application by loading modules that have services with injection token APP_INTERCEPTORS.
It works on my applications. In most cases, it satisfies my needs. It makes the code cleaner and it also resolves a problem with service drilling. That is why I do not reexport interceptors.
But I am wondering why such a feature is absent for injectable middleware.
The example from the documentation shows the usage of MiddlewareConsumer.
I see that it uses an injection token approach. But I am not confident about what container scope it utilizes.
I've tested. It can retrieve injectable not exported services from imported modules...

```js
consumer
  .apply(TestingMiddleware)
  .forRoutes('*');
```